Displaying pandas Dataframe on databricks notebook through ipywidgets gives unwanted output
Take this sample code as a reference, to be executed on a Databricks notebook:
import ipywidgets as widgets

# Create button widget. Clicking this button loads a sampled dataframe from UC table.
button = widgets.Button(description="Load dataframe sample")

# Output widget to display the loaded dataframe
output = widgets.Output()

def load_sample_df(table_name):
  return pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

def on_button_clicked(_):
    with output:
      output.clear_output()
      df = load_sample_df('<catalog>.<schema>.<table>')
      display(df)

# Register the button's callback function to query UC and display results to the output widget
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

display(button, output)

The output has an unwanted list of commas ",,,,,", I think it has to do with the fact that the "display(df)" command gets logged as a json or dict in the Output() method, but how can I get rid of it? I need to display the df as an output and not print it, I need to keep the display(df) but remove the commas, I can't find a way though, please help me!


I can add that if you add the import pandas as pd, this runs fine in current vanilla Jupyter. I recall I was trying help someone and the OP was seeing disparity between ipywidgets in vanilla Jupyter and Databricks, and that OP found, curiously enough that wrapping things in a class helped in that case. I would suggest first trying to play around with maybe wrapping with HTML and trying inside pandas.DataFrame.to_html() that to see if you can something closer to acceptable, and then if that isn't going anywhere try making a class?

The unwanted list of commas is  caused by the way the dataframe is being displayed in the output widget. To remove the commas and display the dataframe properly, you can use the display() function from the IPython library instead of the display() function from the pandas library.
I have tried your code and I am getting the same results like you:

I have tried the below approach:
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
import pandas as pd
button = widgets.Button(description="Load dataframe sample")
output = widgets.Output()

def load_sample_df():
    return pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])

def on_button_clicked(_):
    with output:
        output.clear_output()
        df = load_sample_df()
        # Remove the unwanted commas
        df_html = df.to_html().replace('&gt;', '>')
        display(widgets.HTML(df_html))

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(button, output)

Results:
0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6


In the above code, I am creating a button widget. Clicking this button loads a sampled dataframe. The output widget will display the loaded dataframe. Registering the button's callback function.
In this above code, the load_sample_df() function simply returns a hardcoded dataframe with three rows and three columns. The output dataframe is converted to HTML using the to_html() method. Then, the unwanted commas are replaced using the replace() method.
